# rename export default in index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component called `TModal` that looks like this

```
const TModal = () => {}

export default TModal
```

It lives inside `src/components/Modal/Modal.js`

next to it, there is an `index.js`

this is what index.js does:

```
export { TModal as Modal } from './Modal'
```

Then somewhere in my project, I want to import Modal like this

```
import { Modal } from 'components/Modal'
```

but I keep getting

```
Attempted import error: 'Modal' is not exported from 'components/Modal'
```

What's the problem?

---

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

strcuture

```
src
- components
-- Modal
--- index.js
--- Modal.js
- layouts
-- Auth
--- Auth.js
```

So as an example, I would want to use `Modal` inside `Auth.js`

Comment: What are you doing this in? Browser? Node? Deno? Other? Also, what does your file structure look like.

Comment: @Daniel React..so browser

Comment: @Daniel added both

Answer (score 2):

Since your Modal.js export default, your `index.js` should be written as below

```
import Modal from './Modal';
export { Modal };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not selecting the file (Modal.js) you are just pointing at the Modal directory. This *should* fix it if that is the problem.

```
import { Modal } from 'components/Modal/Modal'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `TModal`. When you export `TModal` from js file remove `export` keyword. everything would be working fine. Help it helps.

```
const TModal = () => {}
export TModal
```